# Delete shared memory segments left over by an Oracle instance

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, unix

We're using Oracle Enterprise 11rR2 running on Solaris.

How can I delete/remove allocated shared memory segments using `ipcrm`?

I'm getting this error:

```
 ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that you know what you are doing....

First find which segment would be a candidate to drop because it was not cleaned up by an Oracle crash:

```
ipcs -bom
```

Take note of the owner and group, they should be the owner of the Oracle rdbms processes. Next check the NATTCH column, should be 0 processes attached to the segment. If you still want to remove that segment (which is pretty safe when there are no processes attached), use the ID column as input for

```
ipcrm -M {your_ID}
```

Normally this does not solve a problem. There was a problem that made the instance crash .... check the alertlog, it could have some clues in it.